# POST Request from iOS (AJAX, https)

Tags: javascript, ios, ajax, post

I'm trying to make an AJAX POST Request from my iOS (Cordova) App. The API URL has a secure certificate on www.myDomain.ch but not without www.
When I test the Request with a tool everything works. I also tried it in a React test application, and it worked.
Only from my iOS App the Request causes in a 403 error. I've tried it with jQuery Ajax, fetch and axios. The Backend also has CORS enabled.

My AJAX call looks like:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'myurl',
   data: JSON.stringify(dataObject),
   method: 'POST',
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(data) {
      console.log('success', data);
   },
   error: function(err) {
      console.log('error', err);
   }
});
```

Requires iOS a special https certificate or is there something I have to add in the Request Header?

Comment: If your server manages to respond with a 403 and your app is even able to receive that, then it means that there hasn’t been an actual HTTPS issue - because if there was, it would not even get that far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to declare the domain in your plist file for your app to meet iOS App Transport Security requirements. See this link:

[App Transport Security](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33)

Comment: Okay I will try to add it directly to the plist file. I already added it to my config.xml (Ionic) and it doesn't work.